# SVG image tag doesn't work on github README

Tags: image, github, svg, readme

I wrote sipmple server with `golang` witch should return a SVG with stats from stack-overflow. Everything works fine as long as it tests the response from my server in a browser or Postman, but when I try to pin this response as an image in the github `README.md` the image I provided from the Stack API does not display properly. This is a example how it's look like:

Via browser:

[image: svg stats from browser]

And result on `README.md` file (this red line is only for emphasize)

[image]

Does Github block images from other sources?
In my case the image URL indicates that the photo is hosted on a Facebook server
`href="https://graph.facebook.com/1432867793574670/picture?type=large`
But does it really matter?

Is there any way to get around this and display this image correctly? Maybe there is some svg image tag attribute that will help to fix this problem?

Link to the repository where this problem occurs: https://github.com/kubo550/stack-stats

This is the exact svg code i get in response from the server:

```html
<svg data-testUserId="14513625" width="158" height="47" viewBox="0 0 158 47" fill="none"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect width="158" height="47" fill="#2D2D2D"/>

        <!-- this is the problematic line -->
    <image x="16" y="10" href="https://graph.facebook.com/1432867793574670/picture?type=large" height="24" width="24"/>
    
    <text x="64" y="23" font-weight="bold" fill="#C4CCBC" font-family="Arial" font-size="12"
          text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle">1,707
    </text>
    <circle text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle" cx="90" cy="23" r="3" fill="#F0B400"/>
    <text x="100" y="23" font-size="12" font-family="Arial" font-weight="bold"
          text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle" fill="#F0B400">1
    </text>
    <circle text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle" cx="112" cy="23" r="3" fill="#999C9F"/>
    <text x="122" y="23" font-size="12" font-family="Arial" font-weight="bold"
          text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle" fill="#999C9F">7
    </text>
    <circle text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle" cx="134" cy="23" r="3" fill="#AB8A5F"/>
    <text x="146" y="23" font-size="12" font-family="Arial" font-weight="bold"
          text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle" fill="#AB8A5F">11
    </text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GitHub serves your SVG through its own domain `camo.githubusercontent.com` and does not directly refer to your image.

```
<img src="https://camo.githubusercontent.com/f9e51abbda49dfb31243a3642e1f4a2f7b31371cf61e23c103c584c189a0791f/68747470733a2f2f737461636b2d73746174732e6865726f6b756170702e636f6d2f73746174733f69643d3134353133363235" alt="stack stats" data-canonical-src="https://stack-stats.herokuapp.com/stats?id=14513625" style="max-width: 100%;">
```

`camo.githubusercontent.com` gets served with the content-security-policy `img-src data:`. This tells your browser from which sources it is allowed to request additional resources, which are only inlined images.

When opening your image in the browser, it gives this error in the console:

> Refused to load the image 'https://graph.facebook.com/1432867793574670/picture?type=large' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src data:".

You need to inline the image into the svg instead of referencing an external url.

Comment: I have the same problem, but if I inline the svg, the old file is still shown in github :/